# Registering a module_load tracepoint using the exported kernel symbol

Tags: c, linux-kernel

While debugging a 3rd party debugging tool, I came across this problematic piece of code:

```
tracepoint_probe_register((struct tracepoint *)kallsyms_lookup_name("__tracepoint_module_load"), hook_module_load, NULL);
```

This code crashes the Loadable Kernel module it is in, because the kernel symbol `__tracepoint_module_load` is not defined in `/proc/kallsyms`.

Normally, this symbol is defined in the kernel's code **[in this macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.151/source/include/trace/events/module.h#L32)**.
I can see that `CONFIG_MODULES` needs to be defined in order for the `__tracepoint_module_load` to become defined in that code.

Does the kernel need to be built with some other options for this symbol to become defined in `/proc/kallsyms`?  Is `CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL` required or something else ?

Comment: Which version of kernel do you use? Does the problem occur on v5.5-rc1 (read: latest vanilla release / release candidate)?

Comment: Debian10 with kernel v4.14.151. Yes